# emacs cpp, struct variable decl/assignment indent issues

Tags: c++, c, emacs, struct, indentation

I'm writing c++ with emacs and I've got a problem with alignment.

For this struct variable initialisations:

```
struct bla
  a={1,2},
  b={3,4},
    c={5,6},
      d={7,8},
        e={9,10};
```

It aligns a and b correctly, but then staircases for the rest, which I don't want.

Note this below indents correctly:

```
int
  a=1,
  b=2,
  c=3,
  d=4,
  e=5;
```

Just when you have ={something} then it messes up.

Is there somewhere I can modify the alignment rules for this to fix it?

So far I've looked at [c-set-offset](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/c_002doffsets_002dalist.html#c_002doffsets_002dalist) and [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC), but I don't see anything to do with variable decl/assignments.

edit:
for javamode inside a function.

```
int func() {
    int
        a=1,
        b=2,
        c=3,
        d=4,
        e=5;

    struct bla
        a={1,2},
        b={3,4},
            c={5,6},
                d={7,8},
                    e={9,10};

                    return 0;
}
```

Edit2: Using (c-set-offset 'statement-cont 'c-lineup-math) :

```
int func() {
  int
    a=1,
    b=2,
    c=3,
    d=4,
    e=5;

  struct bla
    a={1,2},
    b={3,4},
    c={5,6},
    d={7,8},
    e={9,10}; //<-- "statement-cont"

    return 0; //<-- "statement" incorrectly indented to the "statement-cont" above
}
```

Comment: Seems to be a BUG in CC Modes Syntactic Analysis. Hitting `C-c C-s` (c-show-syntactic-information) on wrong indented lines correctly reports syntactic symbol to be `statement-cont`, but the anchor keeps moving instead of staying fixed.

Comment: Yes there seems to be a bug, also if I use (c-set-offset 'statement-cont 'c-lineup-math) it will line up the "statement-cont" parts correctly, but if there is a "statement" below that, it will be incorrectly indented with the "statement-cont" above.